# Simulation of IQ imbalance using MATLAB

Tags: discrete-signals

I already have the value of Image Rejection Ratio (IRR) in dB for IQ imbalanced modulator and I want to simulate this effect using MatLab. How can I obtain $\alpha$ and $\theta$ to calculate the imbalanced gain for I & Q branches ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bottom line:**

You cannot uniquely determine $\alpha$ and $\theta$ from IRR given in dB since it has a dependence on both given by the following approximation:

$$IRR \approx 20Log_{10}\bigg(\bigg|\frac{1-  \alpha - j\theta}{1+  \alpha + j\theta}\bigg|\bigg)$$

Where

$IRR$ is the image rejection ratio in dB

$\alpha$ is amplitude imbalance as a magnitude ratio (typically 0.9 to 1.1)

$\theta$ is phase imbalance in radians (typically -0.1 to 0.1)

This uses the small angle approximation such that $sin(\theta) \approx \theta$ which covers most IRR applications.

For cases where there is no quadature imbalance and only amplitude imbalance the following relationship is exact and you can then solve for $\alpha$ from IRR:

$$IRR = 20Log_{10}\bigg(\bigg|\frac{1-  \alpha}{1+  \alpha}\bigg|\bigg)$$

From which:

$$\alpha = 1\pm \bigg(1-\frac{1-r}{1+r}\bigg)$$

Where 
$r = 10^{IRR/20}$

With IRR given as a negative quantity indicating the image rejection ratio in dB.

For example the amplitude imbalance to provide -30  dB image rejection would be as follows assuming perfect quadrature:

$r = 10^{-30/20} = 0.0316$

$\alpha = 0.9387, 1.0613$

(Or +.51 dB, -.54 dB)

A similar approximation can be given for small angle $\theta$ for when there is no amplitude imbalance. Bessel functions can be used to derive an exact result for $\theta$ applicable to larger angles.

**Details**

If you complex waveform is already generated (as it would be trivial to generate otherwise) you can use the corrections as given in the diagram below (if it corrects a phase and amplitude error it will equivalently induce a phase and amplitude error):

So multiply I by your $\theta$ term and add to Q to add quadrature error ($\theta$ will be approximately your angle in radians using small angle approximations), and scale I by your $\alpha$ term to add amplitude error.

$$I_{out} = \alpha I_{in}$$
$$Q_{out} = \theta I_{in} + Q_{in}$$

[image: IQ Correction]

Both $\alpha$ and $\theta$ will both effect IRR. If the IRR is given in dB, there is no way to uniquely determine $\alpha$ and $\theta$. Note the following to see how IRR can be determined from knowing $\alpha$ and $\theta$:

Graphically it is easy to derive this since a circle represents perfect I and Q balance and results in image rejection. We can see this simply by using Euler's Identities:

Given Euler's Identities as

$$cos(\omega t) = \frac{e^{j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{2}$$
$$sin(\omega t) = \frac{e^{j\omega t}}{2j} - \frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{2j}$$

And a circle with perfect IQ balance as:
$$y(\theta) = cos(\omega t) + jsin(\omega t)$$

$$= \frac{e^{j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{2} +  j\frac{e^{j\omega t}}{2j} - j\frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{2j}$$

$$= \frac{e^{j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{2} +  \frac{e^{j\omega t}}{2} - \frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{2} = e^{j\omega t}$$

Resulting in the well known Euler's relationship as

$$ e^{j\omega t} = cos(\omega t) + jsin(\omega t)$$

The above is insightful as it demonstrates the sideband rejection through phase summation from the I and Q components being in perfect balance and quadrature, and recognizing that $e^{j\omega t}$ represents a single sideband tone (a positive frequency $\omega$ while a sinusoid has two sidebands or a positive and negative frequency).

So similarly we can evaluate the effect of amplitude and phase imbalance. From the block diagram above showing the relationship of $\alpha$ and $\theta$ for small angle approximation when $sin(\theta) \approx \theta$:

$$y(\theta) = \alpha cos(\omega t) + jsin(\omega t) + j\theta cos(\omega t)$$

$$y(\theta) = \frac{ \alpha e^{j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{  \alpha e^{-j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{je^{j\omega t}}{2j} - \frac{je^{-j\omega t}}{2j} + \frac{j \theta e^{j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{ j \theta e^{-j\omega t}}{2} $$

$$y(\theta) = \frac{ \alpha e^{j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{  \alpha e^{-j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{e^{j\omega t}}{2} - \frac{e^{-j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{j \theta e^{j\omega t}}{2} + \frac{ j \theta e^{-j\omega t}}{2} $$

$$y(\theta) = \frac{(1+ \alpha +j\theta)}{2} e^{j\omega t} - \frac{(1-  \alpha - j\theta)}{2} e^{-j\omega t} $$

The IRR in dB would be $20Log_{10}$ of the ratio of the two exponential coefficients given as:

$$IRR \approx 20Log_{10}\bigg(\bigg|\frac{1-  \alpha - j\theta}{1+  \alpha + j\theta}\bigg|\bigg)$$

Comment: I already have the value of IRR in dB and the value of \theta but I have not the value of \alpha. My main question is about obtaining \alpha from IRR?

Comment: i updated my answer. You can only do this if you know that $\theta = 0$ since both effect IRR.